# FindViewById returning null EditText

Tags: android

I have common problem with findViewById() function, it returns null:

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/nameText"
/>

<Button
    android:text="Save"
    android:onClick="buttonClick1"
/>

</TableRow
    android:onClick="buttonClick1"
/>
```

Activity1.java:

```
public class Activity1 extends ActionBarActivity {

    public void buttonClick1(View view) {
        setContentView(view);
        EditText nameText = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.nameText);
        EditText lastNameText = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.lastNameText);
        EditText indexNumberText = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.indexNumberText);

        Log.d(">>>> ", nameText.getText().toString());
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_activity1);
        }
    }
}
```

In buttonClick1() findViewById() returns **null**. Please explain why?

Comment: put proper xml, What do you mean by </TableRow>. Where is <TableRow>

Comment: I can't paste more code, stackoverflow don't let me

Comment: @akcza, please move all your *initializing* to `onCreate()`.

Comment: @akcza if my answer helped to you mark it as a correct :)

Answer (score 0):

Remove `setContentView(view);` from `buttonClick1` method

and initialise all your textview in this manner by removing `view.`

```
EditText nameText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.nameText);
    EditText lastNameText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.lastNameText);
    EditText indexNumberText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.indexNumberText);
```

Also initialize the controls in the xml properly by giving `height` and `width` to controls

Answer (score 0):

Try to replace your code by this one :

```
  public class Activity1 extends ActionBarActivity {



    @
    Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_activity1);

        EditText nameText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.nameText);
        EditText lastNameText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.lastNameText);
        EditText indexNumberText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.indexNumberText);

    }
    public void buttonClick1(View view) {

        //Your stuff
        Log.d(">>>> ", nameText.getText().toString());


    }
}
```

Since now would be the normal code that have you tried, if you want to set a click on a button you'll have to declare it as :

```
Button button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
```

Then you can do the :

```
public void buttonClick1(View v) {
    // Your stuff
}
```

### EDIT

Make sure that you have on your XML all of your `EditText` and all of your `Button` for example :  or , also make sure that you have an `android:id="@+id/yourID` in all of your stuff..., by the way instead of using an `onClick` method in your `XML` for your `Button`, you could use this to use an `OnClickListener`
*The point 1 to 3 should go inside of `onCreate` the point 4 should go outside of `onCreate`.*

1.- Implements `View.OnClickListener` in your Activity1

```
public class Activity1 extends ActionBarActivity  implements View.OnClickListener {
```

2.- Declare it

```
Button button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
```

3.- Do the `setOnClickListener` like this :

```
button1.setOnClickListener(this);
```

4.- Create an `OnClick` method :

```
    @Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    if (View.equals(button1))
        //Your stuff
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Multiple problems unless you're not posting all your code.

1) In your XML you close a `TableRow` tag, but I don't see you opening it. Might just be lazy copy-pasting.

2) In your `onCreate` you seem to be missing a listener for your button. There is nothing to indicate that you have a button anywhere. You need to find the view of your button as follows:

```
Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.nameOfButton);
```

Then you need to set a listener for it like this:

```
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //Here goes whatever should happen when you click the button.
        }
    });
```

3) As for your `ButtonClick1` method, delete it. It looks like you were trying to create a listener, but it is pretty far from what it should look like.